# Can I have SQL incrementally count XML elements while parsing?

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, xml-parsing

So this is my first foray into parsing XML, and I'm trying to figure out how to get this to work how I want.

Given the following XML format:

```
<Tiles>
   <TileRow>
      <TileValue>2</TileValue>
      <TileValue>3</TileValue>
      <TileValue>4</TileValue>
   </TileRow>
   <TileRow>
      <TileValue>2</TileValue>
      <TileValue>7</TileValue>
   </TileRow>
</Tiles>
```

I want it to put it in a SQL table as the following:

```
| X | Y | Val |
|---|---|-----|
| 1 | 1 |  2  |
| 1 | 2 |  3  |
| 1 | 3 |  4  |
| 2 | 1 |  2  |
| 2 | 2 |  7  |
```

Basically, imagine a grid, and each "TileRow" starts a new Row in that grid. Each "TileValue" assigns the Column position in that grid, with the actual TileValue being what's in the 'cell' in that grid.

Is there a way to make SQL 'count' each time it passes over an element, or something to that effect?

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a **minimal reproducible example**. Please refer to the following link:
https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example
Please provide the following:  
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try the following solution.

It is based on the *Node Order Comparison* operator in XQuery.

[Node Order Comparison Operators](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/xquery/comparison-expressions-xquery?view=sql-server-ver15#node-order-comparison-operators)

**SQL**

```
DECLARE @xml XML =
N'<Tiles>
   <TileRow>
      <TileValue>2</TileValue>
      <TileValue>3</TileValue>
      <TileValue>4</TileValue>
   </TileRow>
   <TileRow>
      <TileValue>2</TileValue>
      <TileValue>7</TileValue>
   </TileRow>
</Tiles>';

SELECT c.value('for $i in . return count(/Tiles/TileRow[. << $i])', 'INT') AS [X]
    , c.value('for $i in . return count(../*[. << $i]) + 1', 'INT') AS [Y]
    , c.value('(./text())[1]', 'INT') as Value
FROM @xml.nodes('/Tiles/TileRow/TileValue') AS t(c);
```

**Output**

```
+---+---+-------+
| X | Y | Value |
+---+---+-------+
| 1 | 1 |     2 |
| 1 | 2 |     3 |
| 1 | 3 |     4 |
| 2 | 1 |     2 |
| 2 | 2 |     7 |
+---+---+-------+
```

Comment: Woo, that's some impressive XQuery-fu. But I think `X` is better calculated as `...... return count(parent::TileRow[. << $i])`

Comment: @Charlieface, please up-vote the suggestion: https://feedback.azure.com/forums/908035-sql-server/suggestions/38142115-sql-server-vnext-post-2019-and-nosql-functionali

Comment: Weird, when I copy-paste your code it works perfectly. However, when I adjust the naming a bit, it stops working. The only difference is a few names (which I double-checked), and my XML isn't exactly tabbed properly. Would the latter be the cause somehow?

Comment: @user3813250 Please post your *real* XML and expected output so we can see

Comment: Yup, that was exactly it, the case sensitivity. Thank you so much!

Comment: @user3813250, glad to hear that the proposed solution is working for you. Please up-vote the suggestion: https://feedback.azure.com/forums/908035-sql-server/suggestions/38142115-sql-server-vnext-post-2019-and-nosql-functionali

Comment: Also don't think you need the `for` loop, you can just do `let $i := . return....` whether that is faster, not sure, but I suspect so. Certainly the query plan is simpler

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, SQL Server does not support returning `position()` directly, it only allows it inside a predicate. If it did then you could simply query:

```sql
select
    v.TileValue.value('position(parent::*)[1]','int'),
    v.TileValue.value('./position()[1]','int'),
    v.TileValue.value('text()[1]','int')
from @x.nodes('/Tiles/TileRow/TileValue') v(TileValue)
```

Instead, you can simulate it with `ROW_NUMBER()`

```sql
select
    v1.rn,
    row_number() over (partition by v1.rn order by (select 1)),
    v2.TileValue.value('text()[1]','int')
from (
    select v1.TileRow.query('.') TileRow,
        row_number() over (order by (select 1)) rn
    from @x.nodes('/Tiles/TileRow') v1(TileRow)
) v1
cross apply v1.TileRow.nodes('TileRow/TileValue') v2(TileValue)
```